# Internal Server Error because one cookie is too big

Tags: error, cookie, http-error-500

I don't know the reason but _GPSLSC cookie gets very big after some time browsing our website. So sometimes we get a Internal Server Error and then I have to delete the cookie.

How can I fix it so it won't happen again?

Comment: You can try changing cookie lifetime
Go to: Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> General-> Web-> Session Cookie Management and change COOKIE LIFETIME to 900
(900 seconds = 15 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a magento cookie, it comes from `mod_pagespeed` in your webserver configuration.

See the official documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-local-storage-cache

Search you webserver configuration for any of these:

If you're on **Apache**

```
ModPagespeedEnableFilters local_storage_cache
```

If you're on **nginx**

```
pagespeed EnableFilters local_storage_cache;
```

...and comment/remove this line.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Magento in Ubuntu 14 LTS, nginx, hhvm with php5-fpm for a specific service, i was reading in /var/log/hhvm/error.log

> nFatal error: Stack overflow in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 977

In this case was a conflict between hhvm and php5-fpm.
Shut down php5-fpm and retest it.